# Model validation - Only validate user input fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm pretty lost here. I know how to use validation and I'm currently using FluentValidation on every single project.But one question arises every time I make a new model - *Should I validate only user-input fields or all fields?*

### Example

```
[Validator(typeof(ChatClientValidator))]
public class ChatClient
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string IP { get; set; } // Generated on server
    public int ChatSessionID { get; set; }
    public virtual ChatSession ChatSession { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } // Client field
    public string Email { get; set; } // Client Field
}

public class ChatClientValidator : AbstractValidator<ChatClient>
{
    public ChatClientValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Name is required");
        RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotEmpty().WithMessage("E-Mail is required").EmailAddress().WithMessage("Enter correct E-Mail address");
    }
}
```

Should I validate fields like IP, DateTime etc. (fields that are generated on my server-side controllers?

Answer (score 0):

You should be validating all fields.  Coders have been known to make mistakes and adding some validation or Assert statements adds another layer of assurance that your software performs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I like to Validate all fields that are required for *processing* after the model has been posted back to the server. The logic here is that each "ViewModel" class **can** be used by multiple views then each view will show different aspects of the model and changing what data is shown (and hidden) on the form changes which values are posted back. Any field not in the view will postback null or some invalid value (String.Empty or 0 or DateTime.MinValue etc..) to the controller.

By validating the fields you require for processing you ensure other developers wont forget to add neccesary fields, while "read-only" fields which aren't used for processing can be safely postback as null.

**For example:** I often add `List<SelectListItem>` properties to contain information on drop downs which I probably wouldn't validate, nor would I validate ChatSession in your sample (assuming it's uses to set other values can be replaced by ChatSessionID and ChatSession is there mostly for convenience/display). However I constantly forget to add a hidden field for ID's so I mark them as [Required] to ensure it's always there in my postbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I would have a view model that is a direct representation of your fields on your view. 
I would validate my view model fields only. This, of course is if your are also mapping your updated view model to a domain entity.

Once you have validated your view model and then mapped to your domain entity, your code then sends your domain entity to some other layer for an update to a database.

Before you mapped your view model you would have gone back and got the existing domain model from your database and mapped your changed view model fields into it.

You should then use fluent validation or any other validation mechanism to validate the entire domain model.

Obviously, if your only entity is your view model then you would need to validate every field on that before it hits a database.